# Why CSS rules are disabled

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

Anyone have an idea? why my css is disabled and strikethrough

[image]

Comment: Because another media query presides over another.

Comment: They had a traumatic accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `margin` is overwritten in the `@media (max-width)` query and padding is overwritten in `section#intro`

Comment: ok, i see that... but why the padding also strikethrough

Comment: @woyman1 your padding is overwritten with `section#intro` selector because it's more specific

Answer (score 1):

CSS values can be overwritten based on their [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration,
>   determined by the number of each selector type in the matching
>   selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last
>   declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity
>   only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple
>   declarations. As per CSS rules, directly targeted elements will always
>   take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its
>   ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

because you are more specific here about the element
[image]

and you have written the above property after this
[image]

always the latest written css peoperty and value will be picked by the browser

now. you either be more specific or use !important property